# Start/game over screen

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I am currently making a simple arcade game as I'm beginning to learn how to code. The "gameplay" in itself is done, but I want to add a start/game over screen. I'm also wondering if I should use create_text, state or itemconfig ? I am new to programming, so my program might not be the best.
The code that I made is around 90lines long.
So does anyone have any suggestions on how I should do that (I don't have a clue)
PS : For some reasons I used tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False




class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = self.rect =-2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0


paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Here you can see I added a game_over function. I also changed the way your program works. Instead of using a while loop and sleep. I use the tkinter method mainloop(). Then to run code after tk is added to the mainloop I used the .after() method. After 10 milliseconds the program continues. It then has to continue to call itself in the if statement. Whenever the ball hits the bottom it calls the game_over() function instead of the loop() function. You could add a reset button or something in the the game_over() function and have it call itself until it is pressed. Using these callback function you change the flow of your program without having and checking a lot of bool values in your while loop to see what your program is supposed to be doing.

```py
from tkinter import *
import random


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False




class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = self.rect =-2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0


paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')


def game_over():
    the_text = canvas.create_text(100, 100, anchor="nw")
    canvas.itemconfig(the_text, text="Game Over", width=500)
    canvas.itemconfig(the_text, font=("courier", 50))


def loop():
    if not ball.hit_bottom:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
        tk.after(10, loop)
    else:
        game_over()


loop()
tk.mainloop()
```